# At the molecular level, how is the pressure at the bottom of a lake higher than at the top?

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics

Surely the temperature of the molecules is the same throughout the water. Using $p = \rho g h$ seems to assume a constant density as well. But then how is it that the force per unit area on an object placed at the bottom of the lake will be higher than that on an object near the surface? My first thought is that the incompressible assumption is the approximation at fault, but it doesn't seem that a minute increase in the density of molecules at the bottom of the lake could account for *many times* more bombardments per square centimeter. What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all, the temperature and pressure of a liquid are two independent intensive variables. Either of them may be lower or higher at the bottom of a lake, independently of the other. So let's focus on the pressure.

You are totally right that the incompressibility fails and this is the reason why the lake "knows" about the higher pressure: the density of atoms or molecules becomes somewhat higher. But it's still true that the liquid is "approximately incompressible" and this is exactly the reason why the changes of the pressure are so great even if the changes of the density are minuscule. In other words,
$$ \frac{\partial p}{\partial \rho}$$
is a very large number or, equivalently,
$$ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p}$$
is a very small number. That's what we mean by (approximate) incompressibility and that's why the changes of the density unavoidably linked to finite (or even huge) changes of the pressure are so tiny.

Liquids are nearly incompressible because of Pauli's exclusion principle; the electrons in the atoms are just not allowed to occupy the same state. One has to change the structure of the states but this, because of the repulsion of the charged nuclei and electrons from each other, leads to immense increases of energy. That's why the density of liquids (or, equivalently, the volume occupied by a single atom or molecule) is de facto calculable independently of the pressure.

Comment: @Motl does that mean that when we say the liquids are really incompressible, we come to the conclusion that liquid pressure does not change with depth and we do this by violating the nature of forces?

Comment: No, I didn't write anything of the sort and what you wrote is clearly wrong. The pressure depends on the depth as $h\rho g$, it's easy to calculate, if we talk about the same thing. Incompressibility really means the exact opposite of what you think. It means that it is *easy* to change the pressure by a big amount without changing the volume.

Comment: @I'd really appreciate if you eloborate on how  the pressure changes with depth in molecular level. Thank you

Comment: @Motl, I mean if incompressibility did not fail and the density did not change, how would the number of bombardments increase with depth in a liquid. I just can't understand this.

Comment: The effective number of bombardments hugely increases at huge pressure because the molecules fill the empty room more tightly and as a result, they travel much shorter distance between the collisions. Imagine 1-centimeter balls and the distance between them drops from 0.2 mm to 0.1 mm. The volume doesn't change much but the mean path gets halved, to 0.1 mm, so the pressure doubles.

Comment: I think that your mistake is to imagine the liquid as an ideal gas with pointlike molecules. But you can't make liquids in this way. A liquid is a "gas" that is extremely *far* from an ideal gas, so the nonzero size of the molecules, to pick the most easy to visualize parameter, plays a key role for the incompressibility. And when the size is nonzero, the mean path isn't the distance between the centers of the molecules etc. - the mean path is much shorter, and therefore the pressure is higher.

Comment: @Motl, thank you. This was actually exactly what I had in mind after reading your original answer. I guess I just coulnt express myself well. Perfect 

Comment: @Motl: When you make this statement " Imagine 1-centimeter balls and the distance between them drops from 0.2 mm to 0.1 mm. " 
Then aren't you compromising on the incompressibility? 
Aren't you saying that pressure cannot increase with depth in a perfectly incompressible liquid in which even the change from 0.2mm to 0.1mm is not allowed?

Comment: Dear Devansh, maybe I needed to describe the geometry more carefully. I meant that 0.2 mm and 0.1 mm were the distances from the surfaces - from the nearest points. The distance from the centers of these balls goes from 2.02 to 2.01 cm, OK? In all my examples, I respect the fact that the balls don't overlap. But how much room they have left greatly affects the mean path - and therefore the pressure. The duration between 2 collisions is proportional to the distances from the surfaces, so although the density is nearly fixed, 2+ cm between centers of balls, ...

Comment: ...small changes to the added "epsilon" are sufficient to change the pressure from very high to 1/2 of it or much less. Perfect incompressibility is just a physically impossible limit. That's why I talked about a real-world situation in which the density - through the distance between the balls' centers - changes by a fraction of a percent. The incompressible limit is the 0.1 mm / 2 cm going to zero limit. For some purposes, you may work with the incompressible idealized liquid directly. If you want to calculate d rho / dp and keep it finite, you clearly need to leave the limit.

Comment: Note to readers: When Lubos wrote "it is easy to change the pressure by a big amount without changing the volume", he reversed himself and now agrees that it is in fact impossible to do so.

Comment: I didn't reverse anything, all my statements were right, and if I thought that I have written something important yet untrue, I would have corrected myself. You're just plain lying - I don't quite understand why but it is clearly true.

Answer (score 3):

In a hard-gas model, if you make the atoms spheres, there are indeed lots more bombardments low down in the lake than high up, since hard sphere collisions are the only source of force, and the temperature (hence the mean velocity) is the same. The reason this is violating your intuition is because you are approaching the continuous collision limit, so that when the hard spheres are nearly touching, the number of collisions per-second diverges. The differences in pressure in the hard-sphere gas lead to many more collisions at the bottom then at the top.

But this model is stupid, because the force between atoms on the scale of their separation in a liquid is smoother than a hard sphere. In the real case, you just push the atoms together a tiny amount, and they push very much more against each other, but in a smooth way.